# How IConfiguration.Bind() Works In .NET Core without 'out' or 'ref' in it's Arguments?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, appsettings

In .NET Core we use `IConfiguration` to bind configuration to an instance.

```
var settings = new AppSettings();
Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(settings);
```

To create a similar function like Bind() in my personal project (for a different requirement), I've created a method like this

```
public void BindOption(ref object instance)
{
  ...
}
```

And use it like this

```
var settings = new AppSettings();
MyCustomStaticClass.BindOption(ref settings);
```

Now my question is

How the `Bind()` function works without explicitly mentioning `out` or `ref` in it's arguments?

Comment: Ask yourself this: "Why do you have to do `var settings = new AppSettings();` before calling `Bind()`?  The `new AppSettings()` part, in particular.

Comment: My understanding is bind expects an instance of an object not an object itself. Means a pre-initialized object. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: The only way I could think other than using 'out' or 'ref' is relying on reflection to handle generically which is what I need to confirm here

Comment: That's a distinction that doesn't exist. An instance *is* an "object itself". And yes, it uses reflection to populate the properties of the instance you give it. You would only need `out` if `Bind` were responsible for creating the instance and giving it back to you, but it's not; you created the instance so you don't need it to modify your variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're misunderstanding `ref`/`out` - the only thing they do for you when you're working with a reference type (class) passed into a method, is allow the method to assign a new instance of an object to the argument variable, and the calling code sees the change. They are absolutely not needed to change some data content of the passed variable.

I personally think a lot of the confusion surrounding this comes from the phrase "passed by reference" having a word in it that starts with `ref`, coincidentally being the 3 letters in `ref`

When you make a reference type instance:

```
Person john = new Person(){ Name = "John", Age = 27 };
```

You can pass it to a method:

```
void ChangeName(Person p){
  p.Name = "Fred";
}
```

You don't need to specify `ref` to make this name change and have it stick

```
ChangeName(john);
Console.Print(john.Name); //Fred
```

Internally in C#, imagine that you make `John` and C# allocates some memory, puts the name in it and gives you your variable reference:

```
john --> { Name: "John", Age: 27 }
```

You call the method and C# *temporarily* makes another reference called p (because the method takes a Person p)

```
john --> { Name: "John", Age: 27 } <-- p
```

New reference, same object. You change the name via p.Name, original object is affected

```
john --> { Name: "Fred", Age: 27 } <-- p
```

If we use `ref` C# doesn't make a new reference, imagine it just temporarily renames our existing one then names it back when the method is done

```
void ChangeName(ref Person p){
  p.Name = "Fred";
}


john --> { Name: "John", Age: 27 }      //start with
p --> { Name: "John", Age: 27 }          //when start calling the method 
p --> { Name: "Fred", Age: 27 }          //method changes the person name
john --> { Name: "Fred", Age: 27 }      //method exits, name is changed
```

We never needed ref here

---

Different scenario. Person is immutable. The only way to change the name is to swap it for a whole new object

```
void ChangeName(Person p){
  p = new Person { Name = "Fred", Age: 0 };
}
```

Now, *this* needs ref. Look what happens when we don't have ref:

```
john --> { Name: "John", Age: 27 }
john --> { Name: "John", Age: 27 } <-- p
john --> { Name: "John", Age: 27 }     p --> { Name: "Fred", Age: 0 }
john --> { Name: "John", Age: 27 }
```

Calling the method makes a new reference to the old object, then saying  `p = new...` reattaches that new reference to some new object, which is promptly destroyed at the end of the method leaving nothing changed

With ref:

```
john --> { Name: "John", Age: 27 }
p --> { Name: "John", Age: 27 } 
p --> { Name: "Fred", Age 0 }
john --> { Name: "Fred", Age 0 }
```

Temporarily renaming that reference meant when we made a new object and assigned it, the original calling code experiences the `new` too

---

You need `ref` only if you will set a passed-in thing to a `new` and want the caller to see the new. Most of the time we don't need it

Footnote: `out` is like `ref` except the compiler will check that the method does certainly assign a value. You're required to use "out" or "ref" when passing the variable into the method, because it brings to your attention "this method might overwrite whatever you pass in" (for ref) or "this method will definitely overwrite whatever you pass in" (with out)

Modern .net also has the little-used `in` modifier, which makes the compiler check that you don't assign a `new` anything to a passed-in variable (running the risk of the non-ref scenario where Fred is lost at the end of the method)

Comment: Hey Caius, I got your point. But I'm confused on your answer's 3rd codeblock - "You don't need to specify ref to make this name change and have it stick". To my understanding this is correct for a global variable but not the other way. I was in an impression that pass by value will only create an manipulate a scoped copy within the function

Comment: When we didn't specify ref explicitly it will accept the arg 'by value' and not 'by reference' correct? In that case if you change the var inside that fun scope 'ChangeName(Person p)', It will have no effect on original var outside unless it's a global var. This was my understanding.

Comment: Reference: https://youtu.be/lYdcY5zulXA?t=102 - Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: And this is why I hate the terms "pass by value" and "pass by reference". In simple terms, when you write `Person john = new Person();` C# will make 2 things: one is a big block of data that is the actual data of the `new Person` object, and two a small integer pointer named `John` that is the memory address where the big block of data is found. When you call a method *without* `ref`,it is  the small integer pointer that is copied so you temporarily have two pointers to one big block of data. When you call *with* `ref` no copying is done and the original pointer is sent.

Comment: People think "pass by value means copy" and "pass by ref means original" and that's true, but in the case of a reference type (class) it's the *pointer* that's copied, not the data. Whether you have a copied pointer or original pointer the *data* is still the same one data so you can change the data in either case. The only thing you can't do with a copied pointer is affect where the original pointer points to. If you say `x = new...` then the copied pointer pony's to a new data somewhere else in memory and the original pointer stays pointing to the original data

Comment: The video isn't exactly relevant here because it's using an ` int` as the data

Comment: Alright that makes sense because we are talking about reference types and the video shows value types. Got your point.!